# Customize Office Ribbon programmatically

Tags: vsto, ms-office, ribbon

I am writing an addin to Office (both 2007 and 2010), and have so far used the Fluent Ribbon XML to customize the different ribbons.
The problem I am having now with that approach, is that I want to have a bit more flexibility in my code, and have different modules add more buttons to the ribbon, without hard coding them in XML - The addin is composed of several disconnected modules, and it doesn't "know" exactly what ribbon elements it might need.

Is there a way to do it? I bumped into the [LoadCustomUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(office.12).aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers_Runtime) method on the Application object, but it is not available in C#. Looks like just what I might have used for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 4 (which I assume you're using because of targetting Office 2010), you'll override `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`. More info can be found on this page: [Ribbon Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx). This is also a good read: [Updating the Controls on a Ribbon at Run Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608628.aspx).

Comment: Sadly, I am using .Net 2.0, but I will look into these articles and maybe find some more reasons to upgrade to 4.0 already.
Thanks for the links.

Comment: How to deselect button of ribbon in Word 2013?. I want to deselect the Link to Previous button of Header in Section Break Next Page. If you have any reference or idea then please provide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045209/how-to-deselect-the-link-to-previous-button-programmatically-in-c) @Todd Main